# How to do a query string with a `ClientRequest`?

Tags: javascript, electron

*(I've been using `Electron` for a while but haven't had to do any network stuff – so this is a pretty basic question)*

The [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request) for `ClientRequest` give the example at bottom. I need to pass in a query string like this:

```
https://someSite.com/edd-sl?edd_action=check_license&item_id=549&license=c0xxxxxx
```

---

Is this the correct way to do it (i.e. I cobble together a string "path" - not provide a JSON object, etc.)?

```
const request = net.request({
  method: 'GET',
  protocol: 'https:',
  hostname: 'someSite.com',
  path: '/edd-sl?edd_action=check_license&item_id=549&license=c0xxxxxx'
})
```

---

**Electron example**

```
const request = net.request({
  method: 'GET',
  protocol: 'https:',
  hostname: 'github.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const params = {
    edd_action: 'check_license',
    item_id: 549,
    license: 'c0xxxxxx'
}
const path = '/edd-sl?' + querystring.stringify(params);
```